# How exactly does C++ casting between numeric types work?

Tags: c++, casting, double, uint64

In my code, I do something like the following:

```
double a = 3.0;
uint64_t b = static_cast<uint64_t>(a);
double c = static_cast<double>(b);
```

Interestingly, this works as I would expect (a == c), as long as a is positive, but if a is negative, c ends up as an arbitrarily large positive number. (It must be wrapping somewhere or something.)

My questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Why doesn't this code break strict aliasing rules?

<sup>**Note:** double and uint64_t are the same size on my system.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strict aliasing only comes into play with pointers. As in casting a `double *` to `uint64_t *` and accessing the memory through that pointer, so you don't have to worry about it here. Read the excellent answers at [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) for more information on it.

Also as for conversion, it will try to convert the value held by your `double` into something representable by a `uint64_t`. But `uint64_t` is unsigned and can't represent negative values so you get **undefined behavior** when trying to convert a negative value (also positive valus that are too high and can't be represented). In practice you'll probably get some high positive numbers but you shouldn't rely on it.

---

> C++ Standard (N3797) `4.9 [conv.fpint]/1` says:

> > A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
> > integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part
> > is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot
> > be represented in the destination type. [ Note: If the destination
> > type is bool, see 4.12. — end note ]

It being well defined which Chris Dodd is refering to in his comment only holds for integral conversions, not for floating point conversions which `double` to `uint64_t` counts to.

For more info I also wrote a [blog post](https://www.aliciabytes.dev/floating-point-to-integer-conversion/).

Comment: Actually, casting to an unsigned type is always well defined -- you'll always get the value modulo 2^k where k is the size of the unsigned type in bits.  Casting an out-of-range value to a signed integer type gives you an undefined value (but not undefined behavior)

Answer (score 0):

`uint64_t` means a 64-bit **unsigned** integer, so when you cast to a uint64_t, if the number is negative it overflows since an unsigned integer cannot store negative numbers.

Try it with an int64_t and it will work as expected.